Lee's Smooth Manifolds Problem 10-18
Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Problem 10-18 asks us to prove the following theorem:
Theorem. Let $S$ be a properly embedded codimension-$k$ submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$. Then the following are equivalent:
(a) There exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ containing $S$ and a smooth function $\Phi:U \rightarrow \mathbb R^k$ such that $S$ is a regular level set of $\Phi$.
(b) The normal bundle $NS$ is trivial.
By $S$ being a regular level set of $\Phi$, I mean that (without loss of generality) $S = \Phi^{-1}(0)$ and that for each $p \in S$, the differential $d \Phi_p:T_p \mathbb R^n \rightarrow T_0\mathbb R^k$ is surjective. By $NS$ being trivial, I mean that there exists a smooth vector bundle isomorphism between $NS$ and the trivial bundle $S \times \mathbb R^k$. Note that an embedded submanifold is properly embedded if and only if it is topologically closed with respect to the ambient space (Proposition 5.5 of the same book).
Question. Does the statement of the theorem fail if we replace "properly embedded" with just "embedded"? I didn't use the fact that $S$ was topologically closed anywhere in my solution attempt below. Have I made a mistake somewhere?
Solution attempt. First suppose (a) holds. To show that $NS$ is trivial, it suffices to show that $NS$ admits a global frame by Corollary 10.20. Write $\Phi = (\Phi^{(1)},\ldots, \Phi^{(k)})$. By assumption, the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} \partial_1 \Phi^{(1)}& \cdots &  \partial_n \Phi^{(1)} \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ \partial_1 \Phi^{(k)}& \cdots &  \partial_n \Phi^{(k)}\end{pmatrix}$$
has full rank along $S$. This implies that the vector fields $\text{grad} \Phi^{(1)},\ldots,\text{grad} \Phi^{(k)}$ are linearly independent along $S$. Fix $i = 1,\ldots,k$ and $p \in S$. Let us show that $\text{grad} \Phi^{(i)}|_p$ belongs to $N_pS$. To this end, fix $v \in T_pS$. Then there exists a smooth curve $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \rightarrow S$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. Observe that $\Phi^{(i)} \circ \gamma$ is constant. Thus,
$$\langle \text{grad} \Phi^{(i)}|_p, v \rangle = d \Phi^{(i)}_p(v) = (\Phi^{(i)} \circ \gamma)'(0) = 0,$$
as desired. Finally, define $\sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_k: S \rightarrow NS$ by $\sigma_i(p) := \text{grad} \Phi^{(i)}|_p$. Then $\sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_k$ is a smooth global frame for $NS$.
Conversely, suppose $NS$ is trivial. Then there exists a smooth vector bundle isomorphism $\Psi:NS \rightarrow  S \times \mathbb R^k$.  View $NS$ as a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$ in the usual way, and define $E:NS \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ by $E(x,v) := x + v$. By the Tubular Neighbourhood Theorem (Theorem 6.24), there exists a continuous function $\delta:S \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ such that
$$V := \Big\{(x,v) \in NS: |v| < \delta(x) \Big\}$$
is open in $NS$, $U := E(V)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, and $E:V \rightarrow U$ is a diffeomorphism. Define
$$\Phi:U \xrightarrow{E^{-1}} V \xrightarrow{\Psi|_V} S \times \mathbb R^k \xrightarrow{\pi_2}\mathbb R^k.$$
Then $\Phi$ is a submersion because it is a composition of submersions. It is straightforward to check that $S = \Phi^{-1}(0)$. $\square$

If $S=\Phi^{-1}(0)$, then certainly $S$ is topologically closed in $U$. Notice that if we take an open disk of codimension $k$, its normal bundle is trivial, but (a) cannot hold.

@TedShifrin Could you elaborate on what you mean in your second sentence? By an open disk, do you mean (for example) $S = {(x,y,0) \in \mathbb R^3: x^2 + y^2 < 1}$ as a codimension-1 embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$? In this case, wouldn't (a) hold via $U := {(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x^2 + y^2 < 1}$ and $\Phi:U \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $(x,y,z) \mapsto z$?

Yes, I wrote that sloppily. And you’re right that the tubular neighborhood gives you a $U$. What if $S$ is a spiral like $r=e^\theta$ in the plane? Now the origin will definitely be a problem, no? Hmm … Maybe you win that one, too.

After that, I looked at Jack Lee’s errata on his webpage. You might want to bookmark that link!
